# Django equivalent for Node.js's Bluebird Promises

Tags: django, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a complex use case of promises in an Express (Node) server application, and now I'm being asked to migrate this server to Django. Basically my server (let's call it "A") is an OAuth2 client for another server (let's call it "B") and so A can request resources from B through B's API. Likewise, server A offers its own API which is intended to be consumed through ajax from javascript code in the browser. Let me show you the following picture to make things clearer:[image]

My server A is working like a middleware between the browser and server B. So when the browser makes a call to one of A's API functions, A in turn makes several calls to B's API and based on those results A returns its own stuff to the browser.

So, in terms of code, I was doing something like this in Node.js (the code is just a simplification):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request-promise');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
...

//the following are helper functions

function getStuff1(req,res,params) {
    request.get({
        uri: "http://externalserver.com/api/whatever...",
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'Bearer' + req.user.accessToken //<-- notice that I'm using the user's access token (OAuth2)
        }
    }).then(function(input) {
        //use params and input and compute stuff
        return stuff;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        if(error.statusCode == 401) { // the accessToken has expired, we need to refresh it
            return refreshOAuthToken(req,res)
                .then(function(){
                    return getStuff1(req,res,params); // after refreshing the accessToken, we recursively call getStuff1 again
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    throw(err);
                });
        } else {
            throw(error);
        }
    });
}

function getStuff2(req,res,params) { ... }
function getStuff3(req,res,params) { ... }
function getStuff4(req,res,params) { ... }
...

function refreshOAuthToken(req,res) {

    return request.post({
        uri: "http://otherserver/oauth/token",
        form: {
            'client_id': oauthClientId,
            'client_secret': oauthClientSecret,
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refreshToken': req.user.refreshToken // we're using the user's refresh token
        })
        .then( function(body) {
            jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
            req.user.accessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;
            req.user.refreshToken = jsonResponse.refresh_token;    
        })
        .catch( function(error) {
            throw(error);
        });
    };  
}

// the following is an actual API function

function apiFunction1(req,res) {

    //first we compute params1 somehow
    var params1 = req.whatever;

    getStuff1(req,res, params1)
    .then(function(stuff1) {
        // do something with stuff1 and compute params2
        return getStuff2(req,res,params2);
    })
    .then(function(stuff2) {
        // do something with stuff2 and compute params3
        return getStuff3(req,res,params3);
    })
    .then(function(stuff3) {
        // now make 2 asynchronous calls at the same time
        var promise4 = getStuff4(req,res,params4);
        var promise5 = getStuff5(req,res,params5);
        return Promise.all([promise4,promise5]); //we combine 2 promises into 1 with Promise.all
    })
    .then(function(results) {
        var stuff4 = results[0];
        var stuff5 = results[1];

        //do something with stuff4 and stuff5, and compute the final answer
        var answer = doSomethingWith(stuff4,stuff5);

        res.send(answer); //finally we send the answer to the client        
    })
    .catch(function(error) {

        res.status(401).send({error: error}); // in case of any error, we send it back to the client

    });
}

router.get('/api-function-1', apiFunction1);
module.exports = router;
```

This router is imported later like so:

```
var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/api', api);
```

So as you can see I'm doing a lot of requests to B which include refreshing OAuth2 tokens and making calls to B's API. Now the browser's javascript can call A's API function like so:

```
$.ajax('/api/api-function-1' + extra_params, {
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET'
})
.done(doSomething)
.fail(handleError);
```

So what is the best way to achieve something like this in Django? I'm new to Django and python in general so I'm very open to any suggestion. Does Django have some equivalent for Node's bluebird library for promises? Any help regarding the OAuth2 part is also very welcomed.

Comment: I believe the way your question is currently phrased it is asking to recommend a library, but with a couple tweaks it could address the differences between node.js promises/event loop, and django/wsgi/python request model

Comment: Which name would you suggest then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django conforms to, and is usually served, use the [WSGI standard](http://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html).  WSGI and the default django deployment have a completely different execution model compared to node.

Node employs an [event loop](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/).  Requests come in and are put on a single event loop.  Bluebird (promises) allow you to put an event on the event loop and register an action to perform when that even completes.  Django doesn't have a concept of an event loop, and doesn't have an equivalent to promises/futures (by default).  In django a request comes in and is executed synchronously.  There are a pool of workers, and when request comes in a single worker will handle executing the code until it is finished.  There are no events registered onto an event loop.

Django code will look like:

```
# make an authenticated request using oauth user token

# if request fails make another request to refresh token 

# remake request
```